# How to Setup Google Analytics Events with Isotope Clicks / Get Nav Text Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jquery-isotope

How do I setup Google Analytics to log an event on [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) clicks?

Here's an example of subnav that uses Isotope:

```
<div class="subnavContainer">
   <ul>
      <li><a class="pet-boarding-dog-boarding" data-filter=".pet-boarding-dog-boarding" title="Dog Boarding">Dog Boarding</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="pet-boarding-cat-boarding" data-filter=".pet-boarding-cat-boarding" title="Cat Boarding">Cat Boarding</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the JS that fires Isotope:

```
//Sets up filtering on click of Isotope navigational elements 
$('#isotopeFilters a, .subnav a, #isotopeContainer .isotopeNav a, .page-template-page-home-php #logo').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var prettyselector = selector.substr(1);
    var clicked = $(this).data('item');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Item', 'Viewed', clicked, null, false]);

    location.hash = prettyselector;

    $('#isotopeFilters a, .subnav a').removeClass('active');
    $('a[class="' + prettyselector + '"]').addClass('active');


    $container.isotope({ 
        filter: selector,
        itemSelector: '.item',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 270
        },
        animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

In the JS click event, these two line should do the job, right?

```
var clicked = $(this).data('item');
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Item', 'Viewed', clicked, null, false]);
```

In Google Analytics' realtime view, I see the page views happening, but no events are being shown/logged.

Comment: The event tracking code you have is for classic GA. Is  that the version you are using? Or do you use the newer Universal Analytics?

Comment: @nyuen No it's the newer Universal Analytics. How do I adjust the event firing to work with UA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Analytics event tracking looks like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'some category', 'some action', 'some label');
```

You can use whatever you want for the category, action, and label.

Make sure your event fires by checking in the real time reports, assuming you are not blocking your own visits.

Comment: So like `var clicked = $(this).data('item');
     ga('send', 'event', 'isotopenav', 'click', clicked);`

Comment: Yep! Try that out and check real time.

Comment: Almost there. I see Event Category as "isotopenav" and Event Action as "click," but I don't see any reference to the clicked var. Should that be set as the action instead?

Comment: That means that the clicked var isn't defined correctly. The event parameters can be anything, so just moving them around won't make them work. Unfortunately you will need to debug the clicked var. Can you also check in your Network tab and filter for the 'collect' hits to check the label?

Comment: By the way, to check the label in RT view, you will need to click into the Category link.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm thinking I may have done this wrong. I should probably be changing the default pageview to include the hash and do this all as a page view, rather than event. `ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});`